# Why Git uploads unchanged files again?

Tags: git

I have larger files in my last commit that already is pushed to my feature branch. When changing the commit message (or renaming/moving a file inside the repository) using amend-commit and force-pushing it(*), it takes a longer time to upload the full commit with file contents. So Git does not treat file contents independent from meta information as file name, commit message?

(*) Yes, I know that a) I should not store large binary files in Git and b) should not force-push my own branch - but this is not the question.

Comment: This is surprising behaviour. Git does not care about the name of a file, it stores it by the sha1 of its contents. If that blob was already on the server, I'm not sure why it re-uploaded it.

Comment: Are you sure the blobs are identical? Including meta information like permissions?

Comment: I just reproduced the same behaviour with a files of size 372kb, and the upload was 324kb both times. So yes, OP's observation is reproducible. Now I'm hoping someone in the know can answer, I really want to know too!

Comment: Seems like a job for @torek

Comment: @torek seems to know everything about Git. Is he one of the developers/maintainers?

Comment: @joanis: I'm not. I did put a few small contributions in relatively recently though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git's method of figuring out what objects some other repository needs is (deliberately) imperfect: rather than exhaustively enumerating all potential objects, it simply enumerates a subset of *commits*.  That is, your Git, doing `git push`, tells their Git (over at GitHub or wherever): "I have commit `a123456`" and they say "Oooh I don't have that one, gimme".  This obliges your Git to offer the *parent* of `a123456`; they will check to see if they have the parent, and either ask for it or send a "no thanks already have it" kind of answer.

Now, if you are using "normal" commit sequencing:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- your-main
...--F--G   <-- their-main
```

you offer commit `H` and they say they want it, and then you offer commit `G` and they say that they have it, and your Git can use this to figure out that they have all objects that are contained in commit `G` and all earlier commits.<sup>1</sup>  So only files whose content is completely new in `H` are included in the pack file your Git builds and sends.

If you then build a new commit atop that:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- your-main
```

and offer to send `I`, they'll ask for that; your Git now offers to send `H` again, and they say *no thanks, already have that* and your Git knows not to re-send files (objects) whose contents are in `H`.  (Your Git also gets to delta-compress against such objects.)  But when you use `git commit --amend`, you build a graph like this:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G--I   <-- your-main
```

You offer to send them `I` and they say yes, then you offer to send them commit `G` (not `H`!) and they say *no thanks, already have that one*.  You never notice that they have commit `H`, so when your Git builds a pack file, it includes any objects that are needed for commit `I` but not present in `G`-or-earlier.

Your large file that went over with `H` earlier is indeed in their repository, but *your Git does not realize that* because your Git does not take the shared `H` into advisement.  It could—and perhaps should—since your Git could get a list of all their branch names and commit hash IDs, and this would help in both this specific case, and in the depth-1 shallow-clone case that is probably more frequent.<sup>2</sup>

Doing a perfect job requires a lot more work because they may have commits your Git has never seen:

```
       H   [abandoned]
      /
...--G--I   <-- your-main

...--G--H--K--L   <-- their-main
```

If they tell you that they have commit `L`, that tells your Git nothing useful, because your Git *doesn't* have commit `L`.  If they told you they had `K` too, that still wouldn't help; they'd have to enumerate back to `H` so that you and they hit upon a shared commit.  Alternatively, they could enumerate all tree, tag, and blob objects, but this might make the have/want part of the protocol excessively expensive.  The *common* case, for a successful push, is that you are just adding on to their commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes that there are no *shallow repositories* involved here.  With shallow repositories, the calculations are augmented a bit with "stops" at the shallow grafts during object enumeration.  The *theory* is pretty obvious; the practical implementation details are ... less obvious and I have not delved into Git's actual implementation.

<sup>2</sup>This case is why cloning with depth *2*, rather than 1, before adding and pushing a new commit tends to be so much more efficient.  You'll get one extra commit and some other extra objects, but your `git push` will offer the parent, they'll say that they have it, and your `git push` will now be able to omit the objects they have.  As it is, with depth 1, your `git push` assumes they have *no objects at all* and therefore sends the entire tree.

Comment: So Git always uploads full commits and not smaller parts, e.g. file contents that are reused in commits?

Comment: @ThomasS.: Git knows *something about which commits are there*. Suppose that Git knows that *all of commit `H` is present*. It also knows that it needs to send commit `I`. What *files* are new in commit `I` and totally absent in *every commit `H` and earlier?* Those files must be sent—perhaps compressed against files that are in `H`-and-earlier, or perhaps in whole.

Comment: But, now suppose that Git *doesn't* know that `H` is present and only knows that `G`-and-earlier are present. Git assumes it must send all files that are *not in `G`-and-earlier*. That includes files in `I` that match those in `H`. Git doesn't know those files are in the receiving Git.

Comment: Thanks torek, that's very clear and a very helpful answer!